# WSL OpenSSH will not open tunnels

Tags: openssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-tunnel

I am using WSL with Ubuntu installed. I am trying to SSH to a "jump host" to get to computers behind this host. When I try running the command to create the tunnel, I am getting the following error message:

```
$ ssh -f -N user@example.com -L 0.0.0.0:2201:10.0.0.10:22
bind: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 2201
Could not request local forwarding.
```

The connection immediately closes, and the port is not available (2201). I can SSH directly as `user@example.com` without issue, but I **cannot open an SSH tunnel**.

Can anyone figure out why?

**Edit**: Tried with `-vvv`, received the following output:

```
Authenticated to example.com ([123.123.123.123]:22).
debug1: Local connections to 0.0.0.0:2201 forwarded to remote address 10.0.0.10:22
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr 0.0.0.0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2201.
bind: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 2201
Could not request local forwarding.
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

Comment: Is port 2201 already in use before you try to open the tunnel?  Can you run your ssh command with '-vvvvv' and see if there are any additional debug messages explaining why it fails?

Comment: Can you collect the event logs in windows? The procedure is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) with `logman.exe`.

Comment: Did you try with sudo? [This](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html) website shows only superuser can forward privileged port.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Sudo doesn't help - the port number is above 1024 (so it's not a privileged port, which is all that requires root). I have not tried collecting the log yet, I will need to do that when I'm at work again.